# Why this global heap object not freed?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I have this code:

```
class A {
    public:
            int x;
};

A *b;

void x() {
    A a;
    A *b = new A();
//  delete b; // works. free b.
}

int main() {
    x();
    delete b; //not. why ?
    return 0;
}
```

why b can only be freed inside x() ? not main() ? I thought b is a manual variable, and not scope bound.
Checked with valgrind.

Thank you. :)

**Update:**

Now i remembered. I can use global b with :

b = new A();

Then the delete b on main() can properly delete global b.

****facepalm****

Answer (score 6):

Because the declaration of `b` inside `x()` *shadows* the global declaration; it's a separate variable.  So in your code, the global `b` is never assigned to, so you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

You could manipulate outter `b` this way:

```
 ::b;
```

inside function `x()`, you declared a new `b` which shows `b` in global. You could provide `scope resolution notation ::` if you want to operate on outter `b`.

Comment: This will delete the global b (NULL initialized) but not "b" variable you try to delete. See also Angew's answer.

Comment: Yeah. I notice that i can do    ::b = new A(); too. Thanks for the input. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your function `x()`, you're declaring a local variable `b`. This variable is unrelated to the global variable `b`.

`delete b` in `main()` tries to delete the global pointer `b` (which, being global, is initialised to a null pointer value, so `delete`ing it does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

The `b` inside `x` is different from the `b` in global scope. I don't know what a "manual" variable is supposed to be, but C++ is (for all practical purposes) lexically scoped. So a new variable hides a variable at a higher scope level.